Does the size of a black hole increase with mass?
I understand that extremely minute black holes can have a lot of mass. For example, A Black hole with a 120 pm radius, like a Hydrogen atom, would have a mass of 3.73x10^67 kg. Is this mass already defined? or will the mass increase with size and vice versa?

recommend asking Astronomy SE
